# sampler2DArray - setup and use

Tags: opengl, glsl, jogl

I'm studying OpenGL and I had to use sampler2DArray. I am in torment all day long - all to no avail. I have two questions:

1. How to create a list of textures?
2. How to use sampler2DArray in the shader?

Here is the result of my attempts to create a list of textures:

```
// textures - ids loaded textures
private int createTextureArray(GL2 gl, int[] textures, int width, int height) {
        int layerCount = textures.length;
        int mipLevelCount = 1;
        IntBuffer texture = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        gl.glGenTextures(1, texture);
        gl.glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture.get(0));
        gl.glTexStorage3D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, mipLevelCount, GL2.GL_RGBA8, width, height, layerCount);

        for (int i = 0; i<textures.length; i++) {
             gl.glTexSubImage3D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, i, // error here
                     0, 0, 0,
                     width, height, layerCount,
                     GL2.GL_RGBA, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                     textures[i]);

        }

        // Always set reasonable texture parameters
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        return texture.get(0);
    }
```

Shader example:

```
#version 130
uniform sampler2DArray textures;
varying vec2 UV;
...
void main() {
   ...
   int layer = 0;
   gl_FragColor = texture2DArray(textures, vec3(UV, layer));
}
```

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: `sampler2DArray` works on Nvidia (pre-adding `#extension GL_EXT_texture_array : enable`), on Intel Graphics - no. (Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2), tested on Windows 10 and Arch Linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [array texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture) is *not* a "list of textures". An array texture is a single OpenGL texture, one which individually has a number of quasi-independent layers in it. While you may conceptually think of each layer of an array texture as a separate conceptual texture, in OpenGL (and GLSL), it is a *single object*.

Given this, the interface in your function is incorrect. It should return a single texture object, and it should take as a parameter, not an array of `int` (note: OpenGL objects are *unsigned* integers), but a single integer: the number of array layers to create in that texture.

How you use an array texture in GLSL is simple. Your `uniform` for the sampler uses an array-texture sampler type (for example `sampler2DArray` for 2D array textures). You bind the array texture to the same texture image unit that you specified as the binding for the sampler uniform (just as you would for a non-array 2D texture).

Your GLSL is missing one thing. There is no `texture2DArray` function. The correct function to use is just `texture`. The texture type in post-GL 3.0 is specified solely by the parameter, not by the name of the function anymore.

Comment: I have id already loaded textures (int[] textures). How can I add them to the "list"? And that's what my shader writes when compiling: error: `no matching function for call to \`texture2DArray(sampler2DArray, vec3)'; candidates are:`

Comment: @DBCongard: Oh, so those are live OpenGL texture objects. Well... you can't do that. You don't load data into textures, then turn them into an array. You create an array texture, and load data into it. "It" being singular.

Comment: сan I put the already loaded textures in an array texture? These textures are the same size. If it is possible, how?

Comment: @DBCongard: It would be far easier (and faster) to just load the texel data into the array texture directly. Otherwise, your best-case scenario is to copy the texels from one texture object to another, and that's only directly available if you have [`glCopyTexSubImage` around](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_copy). Without that, you'd have to use `glGetTexImage` to read the pixels to the CPU and then `glTexSubImage3D` to push them into the array texture. Again, just upload the data correctly the first time; it's no harder than putting them into the other texture.

Comment: if I understood correctly, then for the second case I should create an array (buffer) for all the textures, and then add each texture to it using `glGetTexImage`. Then call the method `glTexSubImage3D`, right?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @NicolBolas already said: There is a bunch of problems with the shader code, mostly due to functionality that has been deprecated in version 130:

- There is no method `texture2DArray` in any standard glsl version. There has been one in the EXT_texture_array extension, but this has never been integrated since in glsl 130 all texture lookup functions (texture2D, texture3D, ...) have been replaced by a overloaded `texture` command. If you are targeting 130 without extensions, you should use 
  `texture(textures, vec3(UV, layer))`
- The `varying` keyword is deprecated in glsl 130 and should be replaced by `in`/`out`
- `gl_FragColor` is deprecated and a user defined output (`out`) variable should be used.

You might want to have a look at Section 1.2.1 of the [GLSL 130 Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.30.pdf) which describes the deprecations and how they should be handled. In general I would encourage everyone not to use 130 at all today unless there is a special reason for it. Better move to OpenGL 3.3+ Core Profile and GLSL 330+.